# Filling a two dimensional array with integers java

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to write a function which should fill a two dimensional array like this:

1 -- 3 -- 5 -- 7 -- 9
3 -- 5 -- 7 -- 9 -- 11
5 -- 7 -- 9 -- 11 -- 13
7 -- 9 -- 11 -- 13 -- 15
9 -- 11 -- 13 -- 15 -- 17

Here's it what I could come up with ... by all my logic it should work, but obviously I made some mistake:

```
public class Array {

public static void TwoDimFill(int[] [] array, int start, int inc){
    array[0] [0] = start;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){enter code here
            array[i][j+1] = array[i][j] + inc;
        }
        array [i+1][0] = array[0][i+1];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] [] b = new int[5] [5];
    TwoDimFill(b, 1, 2);

    for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y<b[x].length; y++){
            TextIO.put(b[x][y]+"\t");
        }
        TextIO.putln();
    }
}
```

By the way: This `TextIO.class` is something we use for printing, compareable to system.out ...

Edit: Answered! Thank you a lot guys, you're great!

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: What's the problem? You get an exception? Please next time post it. Also in Java, you usually use List instead of arrays and save yourself code and headaches.

Comment: I guess it's because you are not setting the borders you should start with a loop that makes one or more of the borders valued as i*inc

Comment: @Houssni Shorter code and forget about allocation.

Comment: Original poster (OP), in the future, please include any error messages and details about code misbehavior with similar questions. Please don't make us guess when we really shouldn't have to.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: @m0skit0 Explain to me how creating a "2D" list (list of lists), then filling it with these numbers has *shorter* code... :) I think you'll actually end up a couple of characters longer, because for-each doesn't work here...

Comment: @anorton Using Lists he wouldn't even have this problem, that's why ;)

Comment: @Houssni You can think of a 2D array like 1D array actually, you just need a little imagination ;)

Answer (score 3):

i+1 and j+1 will be out of bounds because you loop until < length. Change it to  < length -1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length -1; j++){
        array[i][j+1] = array[i][j] + inc;
    }
    if (i < array.length -1)
        array [i+1][0] = array[0][i+1];
}
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out on comments, the last output line was incorrect. Variable i can be looped until < length, but it must be verified for the last line that the index won't get out of bounds. Corrected the code above.

Comment: Worth mentioning that arrays in Java are *zero-based*.

Comment: -1, this is wrong - it won't print out the last line correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excess number of operations you are doing. There is a much cleaner, simpler and faster solution. Sometimes a different approach can solve the problem better.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        array[i][j]=((i+j)<<1)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the index is out of bounds before executing the last line in your loop, as well as only making your inner loop iterate up to `length-1` (since indexes for arrays in Java start at 0 and end at 1 less than their length):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length - 1; j++) {
            array[i][j + 1] = array[i][j] + inc;
        }
        if(i + 1 < array.length) {
            array[i + 1][0] = array[0][i + 1];
        }
}
```

This produces:

> 1    3   5   7   9
>   3   5   7   9   11
>   5   7   9   11  13
>   7   9   11  13  15
>   9   11  13  15  17

Note that simply clipping the outer loop to `array.length-1` doesn't work (since in this case you still want the first part of the loop to execute), you'd end up with the following:

> 1    3   5   7   9
>   3   5   7   9   11
>   5   7   9   11  13
>   7   9   11  13  15
>   **9 0   0   0   0**

Bolding is mine, note the last line is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong because of `array[i][j+1]`. If j is the last position `j+1` doesn't exist. You can try this:

```
public static void TwoDimFill(int[] [] array, int start, int inc){
    int aux = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        aux = start;
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = aux;
            aux += inc;
        }
        start += inc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you should always add an explanation of what is wrong with the OP's code. Don't just say _"Try this"_, say _"This is wrong because of problem X. What you have to do is Y."_.

Comment: Ok. This is wrong because of `array[i][j+1]`. If j is the last position `j+1` doesn't exist.

Comment: I know what is the error in the OP code, but add those explanations in your answer directly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really simply, use the following

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] temp = new int[5][5];
        int[][] output = fill2dim(temp,1,2);
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(output[i]));
        }
    }

    public static int[][] fill2dim(int[][] arr, int start, int inc) {
        int[][] output = new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
        for (int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            for (int j = i;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
                output[i][j] = (i+j)*inc+start;
                output[j][i] = (i+j)*inc+start;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

You can remove some loops by just considering the upper triangular matrix, since the lower triangular matrix will be a reflection of the upper triangle about the diagonal